# Best way to create a script to automate a simple process using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, browser-automation

Ok, so I'm a total noob with aspirations of learning to code. I've read about a guy who, for example, wrote a script which, if he was at work past a certain time, would automatically send a text to his wife stating he would be late. I want to do something sorta similar.

What I want in essence is a script that will log in to a website at a certain time of day, check if a box/text is green/yes or red/no, and send a text or notification to my phone informing me of the result each day.

The progress I've made so far is installing Python, installing PyCharm and done some research about tools I could use toward achieving my goal. Selenium seems like it would be capable of logging into the website, but I've no idea how to go about setting up a conditional statement to check the result, nor how I could set it up to send a text/notification to my phone. Also, if there is a more appropriate tool I should look into rather than Selenium and Python, I'm not attached to the idea of using these specific tools.

Finally, I realize that this may end up being too complicated for a first project, so I'd be up for hiring a freelancer to set this up. Equally, if this is something that could feasibly be written by someone with very little knowledge of coding such as myself, I'd really appreciate some direction from an expert!

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Cronjobs which run a filename.py would be the way to do this.

Comment: Selenium would be the right tool for logging in and checking the right element is present.

Comment: sending `text` may need to use paid service [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) if your phone operator doesn't give free gateway to send `text.

Comment: maybe it would be simpler use protocol `IMAP` or `SMTP` to access email account and send email to you from your own email (if your phone has access to email all time)

Comment: I think that you should code it yourself as a little side project, it is always good to know how to code, and selenium is very easy if you understand it, and you have stack overflow to ask any questions if you have any problems

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with selenium for web form automation. Sending notification however would require something else as was pointed out, and if you're on windows you can use windows task scheduler to automate, to performed only on certain time of day etc.

To make things more simplified, you can also look up general purpose automation programs that might support all these features together. For example, JRVSInputs uses selenium for web auto-fills https://jrvs.in/forums/viewtopic.php?t=182 and have features to send email or windows notifications. It can convert all its scripts into a neat batch file, you can then automate this batch file in the task scheduler.

Comment: Your solution sounds like a sales pitch for JRVSInputs.